# SQLite runs during development, not after complied

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, interop

I'm writing a small app for managing a backend file for a Neo4j project. The app is a VB.NET Windows Form project. It uses an SQLite database. The database connection and functionality of read, update and insert works in Visual Studio during development. But when it is compiled either as *.msi or for CDROM if crashes as soon as the database access is attempted with an error,

> Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

I'm not sure why this would need interop. But perhaps because I'm not referencing my database properly for the compile. The db is in the release folder.

I've used NUGet to import references including the SQLite 3.13.0.

The code that works within VS is (Q is the query):

```
Public Class DataLib
    Public Shared SQLiteConn As SQLiteConnection
    Public Shared SQLitecnStr As String = ""
    Public Shared SQLitecmd As SQLiteCommand
    Public Shared myAdapter As SQLiteDataAdapter

     Public Shared Sub OpenConnection(Q As String)
            If SQLiteConn Is Nothing Then
                SQLitecnStr = "Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\db\gfg.sqlite3"
                Dim SQLiteConn As New SQLiteConnection
                SQLiteConn.ConnectionString = SQLitecnStr
                SQLitecmd = New SQLiteCommand(Q, SQLiteConn)
                SQLiteConn.Open()
                myAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQLitecmd)
            Else
                If SQLiteConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    'do nothing
                Else
                    SQLitecnStr = "Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\db\gfg.sqlite3"
                    Dim SQLiteConn As New SQLiteConnection
                    SQLiteConn.ConnectionString = SQLitecnStr
                    SQLitecmd = New SQLiteCommand(Q, SQLiteConn)
                    SQLiteConn.Open()
                End If
    
            End If
        End Sub
```

SQLLite.Interop on NUGet is for a prior version of VS .NET Framework. I'm using v 4.7.2.I've tried adding SQLite Core from NUGet, but this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: In your project and after you compile the application you'll have the file SQLite.Interop.dll, in the release or debug directory. Just copy that file to your root production directory in the same place you have the .EXE file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The SQLite.Interop.dll is not there before or after compiling. I've tried manually adding it but its version is not compatible with VB.NET v 4.7.2. I wrestled with this for many hours without success. I switched over to MS Access and it works well. There is a bug in implementing SQLite in VB.NET. It might work in C++?